# Cómo corrijo este error al ejecutar un proyecto clonado de git sobre Manjaro Linux?

Tags: python

Hola buenas noches tengo un pequeño problema me he montado manjaro como S.O. el cual ya lo he actualizado por completo. estoy tratando de seguir un tutorial de un programa que me interesa probar llamado GOD-KILLER

realice el procedimiento como en el tutorial pero al tratar de instalar la herramienta con el comando "python install.py" me sale un error ya lo intente hacer como super usuario pero me sale error, no se si tenga algo que ver que la persona en el tutorial lo hace con Parrot y yo lo estoy haciendo con Manjaro, les dejo capturas tanto del tutorial como el procedimiento que hice [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola. como sugerencia, procura compartir el código, los logs y los mensajes (en este caso, de la terminal) como texto.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no está relacionado con la distro que elijas. Python es python.

El gran problema es que estás intentando seguir un tutorial aparentemente hecho para python 2.x (algo viejo ya, en desuso). La versión de python que seguro trae tu distro (que es la que yo uso también) es 3.6 o superior (revisa ejecutando `python -V`).

Esa instrucción para python 3 no existe y se usa ahora `input()`. Esto nos dice que el proyecto de tu interés no es mantenido hace un tiempo y nunca lo migraron a python3. La cosa es que elijas si te aventuras a **migrar** todo ese proyecto que clonaste, a Python 3 (implica ir ejecutando y revisando dónde va fallando...). La opción dos es instalar python2 y correrlo ahí, cuidando siempre de usar el comando python2 para indicar que esa es la versión que quieres usar.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias es lo que necesitba de verdad agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Modifica 'raw_input' a 'input' sólo, entonces guarda el fichero y ejecuta el comando de nuevo.

```
nano install.py
```

Comment: Estás en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español y el contenido debe estar en ese idioma. Completa el [tour] para más información.